# GStreamer in Virtualbox: libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, gstreamer, hardware-acceleration, vaapi

I am using **GStreamer 1.2.4** in a **Virtualbox 5.0.4**.

When I start a simple pipeline (like *videotestsrc !  autovideosink*), I am getting an error about problems with graphical hardware acceleration (*va_openDriver() returns -1*).

**How can I make GStreamer work in a virtualbox?**

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc !  autovideosink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
libva info: VA-API version 0.35.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vboxvideo_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null) <--
```

Comment: are you using Intel's Graphics Card or any dedicated one(like, nvidia)?

Comment: I guess the problem is due to incompatibility of vaapi and processor. I am facing similar problem with, `Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller`, please share if you had any luck with this.